# WRITE_TRUNCATE removes RLS rules from table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a job that inserts data in BigQuery using [WRITE_TRUNCATE](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobInfo.WriteDisposition.html) disposition. This will truncate all data already in the table and replace it with the results of the job.

However, in some cases the table I want to insert data into has [Row Level Security](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/row-level-security-intro) (RLS) rules. In this case, `TRUNCATE` removes the `RLS` as well (which I don't want).

As said [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job), with `WRITE_DISPOSITIONS` :

> Each action is atomic and only occurs if BigQuery is able to complete the job successfully. Creation, truncation and append actions occur as one atomic update upon job completion.

I am looking for a way to remove rows from my table without removing RLS, occuring as `one atomic update with the append action upon job completion`.

I have seen that `DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE TRUE` does not removes `RLS`. But I can't find a way to use it instead of `TRUNCATE` through BigQuery Framework. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: As far as I know this is expected behavior on TRUNCATE statement. There is [multi-statement transaction](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions) feature but it is in Preview stage.